How to add margin top for legend in Chartjs (PrimeNG)
My legend is at the bottom of the chart but the space between the chart and the legend is too small,
How can i add margin or padding for the legend, chart ?

Here is my pie chart options, i have added the padding for the layout but it's both decrease the height and width of the layout including chart and legend
const CHART_OPTIONS = {
    layout: {
        padding: 30
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
          title: () => undefined
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'end',
            color: 'black',
            font: {
                weight: 'bold',
                size: 16
            },
            formatter: (val) => val + '%',
        }
    },
}

and the data
const data = {
            labels: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: BACKGROUND_COLORS,
                    data: data.map(_ => _.percent)
                },
            ],
            plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        }


I think this is the simplest way to solve the problem, just create a empty title for the legend, which has the padding property available which can be used to add the space, between legend and chart!
this.options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      title: { display: true, padding: 10 },
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        color: textColor,
      },
    },
  },
};

FULL CODE:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportsModule } from './imports';
@Component({
  selector: 'chart-pie-demo',
  templateUrl: './chart-pie-demo.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ImportsModule],
})
export class ChartPieDemo implements OnInit {
  data: any;

  options: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    const documentStyle = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
    const textColor = documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--text-color');

    this.data = {
      labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [540, 325, 702],
          backgroundColor: [
            documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--blue-500'),
            documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--yellow-500'),
            documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--green-500'),
          ],
          hoverBackgroundColor: [
            documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--blue-400'),
            documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--yellow-400'),
            documentStyle.getPropertyValue('--green-400'),
          ],
        },
      ],
    };

    this.options = {
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          title: { display: true, padding: 10 },
          labels: {
            usePointStyle: true,
            color: textColor,
          },
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
